# how to let the user possess the current cart if sign in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now in my webpage, the user can shop and have a cart without sign in.But request sign in when you want to checkout. But when you sign in, then will create a new cart associating with your user id, what i want is when you sign in, the current cart which dose not have a user id can link to the current user instead of a new one. how to do that?
cart.rb:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
   belongs_to :user
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
 before_create :create_remember_token
 has_one :cart
 def current_cart
  if self.cart.nil?
  self.create_cart(user_id: self.id)
  end
  self.cart
 end
```

sessions_helper.rb:

```
def sign_in(user)
 remember_token=User.new_remember_token
 cookies.permanent[:remember_token]=remember_token
 user.update_attribute(:remember_token,User.encrypt(remember_token))
 user.update_attribute(:remember_token,User.encrypt(remember_token))
 self.current_user=user
end
```

application_controller.rb:

```
def current_cart         
  if current_user.present?
   current_user.current_cart
  else  
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])  
  end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound  
    cart = Cart.create  
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id  
    cart  
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple user class for this, like User and Guest. Guest has a cart, with a user_id, which is nil for a Guest. Then when the Guest becomes a User, the cart is associated with the user.

Check out [the Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations) for this issue (needs pro, though).

Comment: But,how to associate the cart with the user?